# FTP connection fails while SFTP works

Tags: ftp, sftp, vsftpd

**EDIT:** figured it out, I needed to comment out SSL stuffs to make it FTP.

**Problem:**

I'm running sFTP with SSL using vsftpd.

AsI can't access sFTP on browser(without extension), now I want to get FTP working again.

After purge & reinstall of vsftpd, I found out FTP is running on default settings(which can be connected but shows no directory) while sFTP is still running with previous settings. So I decided to keep both FTP & sFTP running at same time.

Then I changed vsftpd.conf as Follows:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=NO
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd_FTP
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
utf8_filesystem=YES
local_root=/home/upload/ftp/
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
```

But after changing vsftpd.conf, FTP is now dead again with "connection is refused", while sFTP is still working properly.

Previous Settings that sFTP was using as Follows:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=NO
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
utf8_filesystem=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/upload/ftp/ETC
allow_anon_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
listen_port=21
listen_port=22
```

**Question:**

1. **[solved]** What part of my config file is causing "connection refused"?
2. How sFTP is still running even after purge, and where is it's setting files?
3. **[solved]** Why 'local_root=/home/upload/ftp/' option is doing nothing?

Comment: in Ubuntu, `sftp` is typically managed by `openssh-server` as embedded into the system.  Do you have OpenSSH Server installed on this system?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, and yes, OpenSSH_7.4p1 says my pi. So that's where this ghost server was hiding!

Comment: Cool, I"ve converted my comment into an answer so you can mark this as accepted and the question as 'answered'/'solved'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only unsolved question is #2:

> How is SFTP still running even after purging, and where is its setting files?

In Ubuntu, the `sftp` server mechanism is typically done as part of an SSH server.

If you are running `openssh-server` to have SSH access, then that is handling the SFTP protocol connections.